# Build json objects based on existing json-object-templates in nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I would like to generate some requests based on an exisitng json-file:

It looks like this:

```
[ 
    {   "SearchIndex": "Wine",
        "Title": "Wine",
        "MinimumPrice": 5000,
        "MaximumPrice": 1000000,
        "KeyWords": "Red Wine, White Wine, Bordeaux"
    },
    {
        "SearchIndex": "Wireless",
        "Title": "Wireless",
        "MinimumPrice": 100,
        "MaximumPrice": 1000000,
        "KeyWords": "Wifi, Cisco, Router"
    }
]
```

My problem is that I would like to generate a huge amount of requests based on only a few request-template by modifying this:

- I want to generate new Minimum/MaximumPrices based on the given range
  by incrementing by 500. f.e.: new Object = {...,'MinimumPrice':
  5000, 'MaximumPrice': 5500,...}
- I want to do the same thing at the same time with "Keywords" meaning:
  Extracting each Keyword and then re-writing the values: If I got 3
  Keywords, 3-times more Query-Objects would result.
- Both modifications should work together/in a row.

Could you please give me an implementation guideline - I ask not for the code - I want to do it myself; but I am stuck...

The result could either be in an array or written into another json-file.

Thank you!

Hucho

Comment: why don't you write a JSON schema and generate fake object from the schema. you can  search for `generate json from schema` and you will get plenty of results.

Comment: I will try that; thank you